# SOIL_load_OGL_texture returning NULL, possibly a working directory issue (XCode 6)

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, soil

Ok, so I'm trying to use SOIL to load a .png file that's in a "textures" folder. The textures folder is located in the same directory as the code. I've gone into the scheme settings on the XCode project and changed the working directory to the one where the folder is located. However, when I do this simple test, it always indicates that the GLUint texture is NULL.

```
GLuint texture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
(
 "textures/image.png",
 SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
 SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
 SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
 );

if (texture == 0){
    std::cout << "Texture not found!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong in regards to SOIL but my hunch is that the file is simply not being read. As I said, I changed the working directory in XCode but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Call `SOIL_last_result` to get an error message, and print it out.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo It says "PNG not supported: 8-bit only". OK, so it does find the file. However, if I try to change the image to an 8-bit PNG or an 8-bit JPG, it gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at the line where I'm assigning the variable 'texture'.

Comment: Can you get a traceback to where in SOIL it crashes? Also make sure you have an OpenGL context set up before loading the texture.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Yeah, that was the problem. It's working now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured it out. Problem was that the PNG file was 16-bit instead of 8-bit. Also, the `SOIL_load_OGL_texture` function needed to be called after `glfwCreateWindow()` and `glfwMakeContextCurrent()`.

Here's the answer that helped me: [SOIL: 'Unable to open file' in C++ and OpenGL with Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012026/soil-unable-to-open-file-in-c-and-opengl-with-xcode)